# "You don't have permission to use this type of flag"?

Tags: feature-request

So I was sitting in the First Post review queue minding my own business when a post that was obvious spam came up all over the screen.

I decided to flag it as spam, as one would do, but I was then presented with the error message (shown below) "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag".

[image]

Now, after some research it turns out the question was already deleted, possibly while I was busy watching episode 4 of Gotham.

Could we perhaps get a better error message for that? When I moved to downvote the question I was informed that it was already deleted, why could I not have been told that when I tried to flag it?

Comment: same request on meta.SE though http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233560/flagging-a-deleted-post-should-not-give-you-dont-have-permission

Comment: "minding my own business", yeah, sure you were...

Comment: @gunr2171 He was at home, all night...

Comment: I have some catching up to do on Gotham...